# how to show rating in email using markdown in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, markdown, html-email

in markdown svg not supported so if we want to show ratings like that
we can put emoji like that so we can put black and white emoji also
⭐⭐⭐ ☆ ☆

but how can i show it in a better way like that using markdown in laravel php
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMbJs.png)

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">

    @php
        $rating = $review ? $review->rating : 0;
        $emptyStars = 5 - $rating;
    @endphp

    @for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
        <svg class="star" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; fill: {{ $i <= $rating ? 'yellow' : 'transparent' }}"
            aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 22 20">
            <path
                d="M20.924 7.625a1.523 1.523 0 0 0-1.238-1.044l-5.051-.734-2.259-4.577a1.534 1.534 0 0 0-2.752 0L7.365 5.847l-5.051.734A1.535 1.535 0 0 0 1.463 9.2l3.656 3.563-.863 5.031a1.532 1.532 0 0 0 2.226 1.616L11 17.033l4.518 2.375a1.534 1.534 0 0 0 2.226-1.617l-.863-5.03L20.537 9.2a1.523 1.523 0 0 0 .387-1.575Z" />
        </svg>
    @endfor
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i got a solution for markdown here is the simple mail code
using html-css

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; font-size: 25px;">
    @for ($i = 1; $i <= $review->rating; $i++)
        <span style="color: gold;">&#9733;</span>
    @endfor
    @for ($i = $review->rating + 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
        &#9734;
    @endfor
</div>
```

it can be more simple but it is good and working fine for giving a rating out of 5